# Which end of the wire is positive in this case?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

In this question, the uniform magnetic field into the page is increasing at a constant rate. So the induced emf in both the top loop and the bottom loop will try to induce an anticlockwise current. I am just trying to figure out which side would be positive and which side would be negative.
Is my bottom drawing correct?
[image]

Because emf is the influence that makes charge go from lower to higher potential, that is why I have drawn it this way. But not sure if I am correct.

(Of course, I am aware that since the bottom loop has a larger area, the induced emf in the bottom loop will win, and the emf and current is clockwise in the top loop ultimately. But just for the sake of argument.)

Comment: The electric field is non-conservative, so you cannot define a potential function.